Arnold ODE Dilation phase space
In Arnold's ODE book, he discusses a first-order homogeneous linear equation on pg 48:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x) y$$
And then gives the following remark:

Remark 2 Dilating the extended phase space $(x, y)$ along the $y$-axis maps the direction field of the homogeneous linear equation (1) [note: this is the quation above] into itself. Therefore the integral curves map into one another under the action of dilations along the y-axis. They can all be obtained from any one of them by dilations (Fig. 39).

Fig 39 is given in the MSE question here.
Can someone explain this? I don't understand how the dilation works or how integral curves map onto each other.

A dilation along the $y$-axis is a map: $(x,y)\mapsto(x,ay+b)$ where $a,b$ are constants. As far as I can tell quickly Arnold assumes $b=0,.$
Can you solve that ODE? Write down the solution and we discuss dilations further. BTW: the axis labels at Arnold's Fig. 39 I find strange. Imho $y$ is a function of $x$ and not vice versa.

Fig. 39 was driving me crazy, thanks for clarifying that it is probably a typo!!
